# cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'voto'), and others properties

Tags: node.js, docker, rabbitmq, nestjs

my asynchronous function that basically works when a high prestige user evaluates a question from a common user, he gives an upvote or downvote, if the question has a -1 vote, the common user loses prestige, but it gives an error that I will show after the codes .

my service(question - rabbitmq):

```
async usuarioPrestigiadoAtualiza(idUsuario: string, idUsuarioPropio: string, idPergunta: string,   dados: atualizaEspecificoDTO) {
    
    
    const usuario = await this.usuarioMetaRepository.findOne({where: {id: idUsuario}})
    if(usuario === null){
      throw new NotFoundException('Usuario Prestigiado nao existe')
    }
    const usuario2 = await this.usuarioMetaRepository.findOne({where: {id: idUsuarioPropio}})
    if(usuario2 === null){
      throw new NotFoundException('Usuario Propio nao existe')
    }
    // if(usuario2.pergunta.id !== perguntaAchada.id){
    //   throw new UnauthorizedException('Usuario Propio nao possui essa pergunta')
    // }
    const perguntaAchada = await this.perguntaRepository.findOne({where: {id: idPergunta}})
    if(perguntaAchada === null){
      throw new NotFoundException('Pergunta nao existe')
    }
    
    
    if(usuario.prestigio < 100){
      throw new UnauthorizedException(`Usuario: ${usuario.nome} nao possui prestigio suficiente!`)
    }
    if (dados.voto === -1) {
      usuario2.prestigio -= 5;
      usuario2.voteForce -= 2;
    } else if (dados.voto >= 1) {
      for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (usuario2.pergunta.voto + 1) {
          usuario2.prestigio += 4;
          usuario2.voteForce += 1;
        }
      }
    }
    if (usuario.voteForce > 30) {
      dados.voto *= 2;
    }
    if (usuario.voteForce > 60) {
      dados.voto *= 3;
    }
    if (usuario.voteForce >= 100) {
      dados.voto *= 4;
    }
    if(usuario2.prestigio >= 100){
      usuario2.prestigio === 100
    }
    // if(dados.voto >= -10){
    //   return await this.perguntaRepository.remove(perguntaAchada)
    // }

    perguntaAchada.id = dados.id
    perguntaAchada.titulo = dados.titulo
    perguntaAchada.voto = dados.voto
    perguntaAchada.pergunta = dados.pergunta
    const perguntaMudadaPorPrestigiado = await this.perguntaRepository.save(perguntaAchada)
    console.log(perguntaMudadaPorPrestigiado)
    return perguntaMudadaPorPrestigiado

  }
```

my controler if need(rabbitmq)

```
 @MessagePattern({ cmd: 'put-perguntaPrestigio'})
  async enviarPerguntaAvaliada(@Ctx() contexto: RmqContext, @Payload() payload: { idUsuario: string; idUsuarioPropio: string; idPergunta: string; dados: atualizaEspecificoDTO }){
    const channel = contexto.getChannelRef()
    const message = contexto.getMessage()
    channel.ack(message)

    return this.perguntaService.usuarioPrestigiadoAtualiza(payload.idUsuario, payload.idUsuarioPropio, payload.idPergunta, payload.dados )
```

api gateway controler:

```
@Put('usuarioM/:id1/:id2/:id3')
  async perguntaAtualizaPorPrestigiado(@Param('id1') idUsuario: string, @Param('id2') idUsuarioPropio: string, @Param('id3') idPergunta: string,  @Body() data: atualizaEspecificoDTO) {
    return this.authServico.send(
      {
        cmd: 'put-perguntaPrestigio'
      }, {idUsuario, idUsuarioPropio, idPergunta, data}
    )
  }
```

As I said, I need a high-prestige user to evaluate a common user, but when I try to post the user's question, it says:

```
ERROR [RpcExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'voto')
```

when I remove vote, it happens with id, if I remove id, it happens with the title and so on, all the properties of the DTO, I was using an entity but I preferred to update the question found (perguntaAchada), as if it didn't get the information from postman, I already tried logging and nothing came out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't sending an object with a `dados` property to your microservice from the gateway controller. The object's properties are `idUsuario`, `idUsuarioPropio`, `idPergunta`, and `data`. It *looks* like you are expecting `dados` to be the `data` property, and if that's the case then you should update your types accordingly

Comment: it worked,I didn't know, I thought the conversion was automatic, thanks jay